# Ошибка С2065: необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с проблемой, но на существующих топиках об этой проблеме не нашел решения. Я в затруднении, все include'ы правильно расставлены вроде, да и средствами visual studio у меня получается перейти к объявлению функции, а ошибка все равно вылетает: "С2065. resizeCallback: необъявленный идентификатор". Вот код:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define internal static
#define local_persist static
#define global_variable static


namespace core {
namespace graphics {
    class Window
    {
        private:
            const char* name;
            int width, height;
            GLFWwindow* window;

        public:
            Window(const char* name, int width, int heignt);
            ~Window();

            bool closed();
            void MainLoop();

        private:
            bool init();
            void clear();
            void update();
            void render();

            friend void resizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
    };
}}
```

Вот второй файл

```
#include "window.h"

namespace core {
namespace graphics {

    Window::Window(const char* name, int width, int height)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;

        if (!init())
        {
            glfwTerminate();
        }
    }

    Window::~Window()
    {
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    bool Window::init()
    {
        if (!glfwInit())
        {
            std::cout << "LooL. GLFW isn't ok" << std::endl;
            glfwTerminate();
            return false;
        }

        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, name, NULL, NULL);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, resizeCallback);

        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "glew isn't okay" << std::endl;                
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void Window::update()
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    void Window::clear()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }


    void Window::render()
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
        glEnd();
    }

    void Window::MainLoop()
    {
        update();
        clear();
        render();
    }

    bool Window::closed()
    {
        return (glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) == 1;
    }

    void resizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

}}
```

Comment: первый скрин- window.h(хедер), второй windows.cpp

Comment: Замените картинки обычным текстом. Тем более что из картинок непонятно, **где** объявлена `resizeCallback`.

Comment: @Harry , так лучше?

Comment: Строчку, в которой происходит ошибка, кто будет указывать? Пушкин?

Comment: Вам стоит сократить код [до минимального](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и привести лог сборки полностью

Comment: @AnT , я раньше ни разу не вставлял код в посты, да и это мое третье обращение сюда, учту в будущем, спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявление функции как `friend` внутри класса *ссылается* на функцию из охватывающего namespace (`namespace graphics` в вашем случае), но **не создает** видимого объявления этой функции в охватывающем namespace. Поэтому ваша `resizeCallback` - невидима до тех пор, пока вы ее явно не переобъявите на уровне namespace.

На уровне namespace ваша `resizeCallback` объявлена в самом низу файла. Это значит, что выше по файлу `resizeCallback` является "необъявленным идентификатором".

(Увидеть такую "невидимую" функцию может только Argument Dependent Lookup, но к вашему случаю это не относится.)

Либо перенесите определение `resizeCallback` в самое начало `namespace graphics`. Либо (лучше) добавьте ее явное объявление прямо в хедере, рядом с определением класса.

Comment: спасибо большое, я перенес  функцию resizeCallback выше функции init, где она используется и у меня все получилось)